# XSD for XML with namespaced and no namespace elements combined

Tags: xml, xsd

I receive this kind of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root-element xmlns="SomeSpecificNameSpace">
    <some-elements />
    <some-other-elements/>
    <some-other-other-element/>
    <element-with-empty-namespace xmlns=""/>
</root-element>
```

I must make a check that I've this `element-with-empty-namespace`, but that I don't care about the content, so I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema          targetNamespace="SomeSpecificNameSpace"
                    elementFormDefault="qualified"
                    xmlns="SomeSpecificNameSpace"
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="MyRootElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            <!-- Others types here -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>           
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="element-with-empty-namespace" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" xmlns="">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:anyAttribute/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema
```

but it seems it doesn't accept my element, saying that it is expecting an element with the namespace `SomeSpecificNameSpace`.

I know that this structure is a little bit weird, but this `element-with-empty-namespace` is one "value" we provide through XML.

Comment: I believe that `element-with-empty-namespace` "inherits" `SomeSpecificNamespace` simply by being declared inside `root-element`

Comment: Yes, but my input xml is not with the same namespace everywhere

Comment: The XML you need to process is exactly like the sample you provided? I am talking about the XML not the xsd.

Comment: Besides, the `element-with-empty-namespace` should be inside the `MyRootElement` which name should be `root-namespace` according the xml sample.

Answer (score 2):

**Multiple namespaces require multiple XSDs.**

To support your XML input structure,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root-element xmlns="SomeSpecificNameSpace"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="SomeSpecificNameSpace try.xsd">
  <some-elements />
  <some-other-elements/>
  <some-other-other-element/>
  <element-with-empty-namespace xmlns=""/>
</root-element>
```

break your XSD into two files as follows...

In the main XSD file, which governs the `SomeSpecificNameSpace` namespace, use `xs:import`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="SomeSpecificNameSpace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:import schemaLocation="element-with-empty-namespace.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="root-element">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="some-elements"/>
        <xs:element name="some-other-elements"/>
        <xs:element name="some-other-other-element"/>
        <xs:element ref="element-with-empty-namespace"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and import a second XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="element-with-empty-namespace">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:anyAttribute/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

that houses the `element-with-empty-namespace` element in no namespace.