# Create specific SOAP XML message using WSDL

Tags: xml, wsdl, soapui

I'm trying to understand how WSDL works and how to create one. Basically, my issue is that I'd like to create a request with a specific XML structure.
This is the part of XML that I'm changing:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   targetNamespace="http://www.kba.de/coc" 
   elementFormDefault="qualified" 
   attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="coc-mitteilung">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="InitialVehicleInformation">
              <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
                 </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The result request comes formatted as follows in SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:coc="http://www.kba.de/coc">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <coc:coc-mitteilung>
     <coc:InitialVehicleInformation>
        <coc:firstname>Name</coc:firstname>
        <coc:lastname>Surname</coc:lastname>
        <coc:address>Address</coc:address>
     </coc:InitialVehicleInformation>
  </coc:coc-mitteilung>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But what i want to achieve is the following XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:coc="http://www.kba.de/coc">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <coc:coc-mitteilung>
     <InitialVehicleInformation>
        <firstname>Name</firstname>
        <lastname>Surname</lastname>
        <address>Address<address>
     </InitialVehicleInformation>
  </coc:coc-mitteilung>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So from the level `InitialVehicleInformation`, I do not want to specify the `coc` prefix in the generated request. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want that format?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381877/xsd-for-xml-with-namespaced-and-no-namespace-elements-combined